# Not sure how to append array outside of async call

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to get certain child nodes named City from Firebase using `observeSingleEvent` but I am having issues trying to pull it into the main thread. I have used a combination of completion handlers and dispatch calls but I am not sure what I am doing wrong, in addition to not being that great in async stuff. In `viewDidLoad` I'm trying to append my keys from the `setupSavedLocations` function and return it back to `savedLocations` I feel like I am close. What am I missing?

Edit: Clarity on question

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

class SavedLocationsViewController: UIViewController {

    var userID: String?
    var savedLocations: [String] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        setupSavedLocations() { (savedData) in
            DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                self.savedLocations = savedData
                print("inside", self.savedLocations)
            })
        }
        print("outside",savedLocations)
    }

        func setupSavedLocations(completion: @escaping ([String]) -> ()) {
        guard let user = userID else { return }
        let databaseRef = Database.database().reference(fromURL: "https://************/City")
        var dataTest : [String] = []
        databaseRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {(snapshot) in
            let childString = "Users/" + user + "/City"
            for child in snapshot.children {
                let snap = child as! DataSnapshot
                let key = snap.key
                dataTest.append(key)
            }
            completion(dataTest)
        })
    }
```

sample output

```
outside []
inside ["New York City", "San Francisco"]
```

Comment: Your code is not showing anything wrong. Anyway, just a little observation, you may want assign `savedLocations` just before the `main.async`:  `setupSavedLocations() { (savedData) in self.savedLocations = savedData DispatchQueue.main.async`, then if you need to refresh some components, eg: `UITableView`, you must do it inside `main.async`

Comment: What is the reason to have it outside of main.async? And does that mean there is no way to have my savedLocation available on the main thread?

Comment: What do you mean by "issues trying to pull it into the main thread"? If you're referring to the "outside" print statement not listing locations, that's because it's getting called before setupSavedLocations finishes. It's async, so it won't block your viewDidLoad while it's running.

Comment: I guess the better question is how do I show the “outside” statement with the locations?

Comment: I don't see any reason why you should wait or change the thread for assigning `savedLocations` and also I am asking you the opposite: "What is the reason to have it inside of `main.async`?". You should put inside `main.async` only things related to the user interface (eg: `tableView.reloadData`), anyway in case you need `savedLocations`, since is a property, is obviously visible anywhere/anytime.

Comment: What you are missing is that `self.savedLocations` does not have values until the completion handler is called. You have to wait until that happens to use any of those values. If you want to then show the results of the `setupSavedLocations` call then you should do it in the completion handler or create a func like `func showSavedLocations(locations: [City])` and call that in the completion handler. So in `viewDidLoad` you would show a spinner to the user indicating that a network call is being made and then when the completion handler is called you would remove it and show the saved cities.

Comment: Do Firebase callbacks get called on a background thread? I have a vague memory of reading that the callbacks are invoked on the main thread, but after a little searching I wasn't able to determine it one way or the other.

Comment: @AllenR I'm struggling a bit to understand that, could you happen to post an example as a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The call to `setupSavedLocations` is asynchronous and takes longer to run than it does for the cpu to finish `viewDidLoad` that is why your data is not being shown. You can also notice from your output that `outside` is called before `inside` demonstrating that. The proper way to handle this scenario is to show the user that they need to wait for an IO call to be made and then show them the relevant information when you have it like below.

```
class SavedLocationsViewController: UIViewController {

    var myActivityIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        setupSavedLocations() { (savedData) in
            DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                showSavedLocations(locations: savedData)
            })
        }
        // We don't have any data here yet from the IO call
        // so we show the user an indicator that the call is 
        // being made and they have to wait

        let myActivityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(activityIndicatorStyle: UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.gray)        
        myActivityIndicator.center = view.center        
        myActivityIndicator.startAnimating()
        self.view.addSubview(myActivityIndicator)
        self.myActivityIndicator = myActivityIndicator
    }

    func showSavedLocations(locations: [String]) {
        // This function has now been called and the data is passed in.
        // Indicate to the user that the loading has finished by 
        // removing the activity indicator
        myActivityIndicator?.stopAnimating()
        myActivityIndicator?.removeFromSuperview()

        // Now that we have the data you can do whatever you want with it here
        print("Show updated locations: \(locations)")
    }
```